# What should I put as condition in OnActionExecuting to avoid an infinite redirect loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a global filter:

```
public class GeoLookupActionFilter : IActionFilter
{    
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
         if (condition?) // What should I put as condition on this line to avoid an infinite redirect loop?
            return;

         if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["localization"] != null)
         {
             var isoCode = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["localization"];

             if (isoCode == "en-us")
             {
                 context.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.company.com/en-us/home");
             }

             if (isoCode == "es-mx")
             {
                 context.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.company.com/es-mx/casa");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

What should I put as condition on line 5 in `OnActionExecuting` to avoid an infinite redirect loop?

Edit: The `RedirectResult` would also probably need to look something like this (because I don't want to redirect to an external URL; I want to redirect to the `Index` action method of the `Home` controller):

```
new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = _controller, action = _action})
                );
```

and I would probably need to add /en-us/home or /es-mx/case in addition to that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get Url referrer uisng `Request` object and compare it with current Url. If they are same you can bypass other codes

Comment: I don't think this would work if I would refresh the page. Then the condition would fail because the previous url would be the same as the current.

Comment: You're also assuming that the browser will send the `Referer:` header at all; in fact, many browsers _don't_ send the header, so you must never rely on it (in fact, _never_ trust remote clients anyway).